# Javascript variable not changing inside setInterval() function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The variable `counter` does not change for some reason, it stays its initial value, of 50. It's a global variable, that is tried to be changed inside a function called by setInterval().

```
var mode = false;
var counter = 50;
var interval = null;
var increment = false;
var MAX = 50;
var MIN = 0;
var INTERVAL_MS = 3000;

setInterval(doInterval, INTERVAL_MS);

function doInterval() {
    if(increment)
    {
        counter += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Decrement, " + counter);
        counter -= 1;
    }

    // Set direction
    if(counter = MIN)
    {
        increment = true;
    }
    else if(counter = MAX)
    {
        increment = false;
    }

    console.log("set to " + counter + " (D) Increment next time? " + increment);

    // dosomething with the values
}
```

The output from this code

> decrement, 50
>
> set to 50 (D) Increment next time? false
>
> decrement, 50
>
> set to 50 (D) Increment next time? false
>
> decrement, 50
>
> set to 50 (D) Increment next time? false
>
> And so on

Since it's 50 and increment is false, it should become 49, 48, however it seems that I can't change the variable's value. What could be a reason? The code is run inside a NodeJS app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

these lines

```
if(counter = MIN)
```

and

```
else if( counter = MAX )
```

are setting counter to MIN or MAX. You want to `===` triple equals (`==` is fine in this case) to check for equality.

Comment: Ah such a newbie mistake.. Had a hard time seeing it because I was programming in the terminal.. This fixed it of course!

Answer (score 1):

= is for assignment and == is equality check (=== for strict check). Please use equality check to fix your code.

```
// Set direction
    if(counter == MIN)
    {
        increment = true;
    }
    else if(counter == MAX)
    {
        increment = false;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, please add some kind of commentary about why this works.

Answer (score 0):

You were accidentally assigning values in your if statement. Try this to fix it.

At this part

```
  if(counter == MIN)
  {
    increment = true;
  }
  else if(counter == MAX)
  {
    increment = false;
  }
```

To fix it you can use this:

```
var mode = false;
var counter = 50;
var interval = null;
var increment = false;
var MAX = 50;
var MIN = 0;
var INTERVAL_MS = 3000;

setInterval(doInterval, INTERVAL_MS);

function doInterval() {
  if(increment)
  {
    counter += 1;
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("Decrement, " + counter);
    counter -= 1;
  }

  // Set direction
  if(counter == MIN)
  {
    increment = true;
  }
  else if(counter == MAX)
  {
    increment = false;
  }

  console.log("set to " + counter + " (D) Increment next time? " + increment);

  // dosomething with the values
}
```